# Lightning Out SLDS Weirdness

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, slds, lightning-out

I am trying to load a `lightning out` app in a static site hosted via an S3 bucket.  I started with a lightning app that extends `ltng:outApp` and it describes a single component as a dependency.  The app loads and the component is rendered, but only some of the styling is actually being applied. The component does contain a flow, so maybe there's something I forgot there?

In the developer console I see

> Access to Font at 'https://[MY_SANDBOX]/_slds/fonts/v2.3.0/SalesforceSans-Regular.woff2' from origin '[MY_STATIC_SITE]' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '[MY_STATIC_SITE]' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Access to Font at
>   'https://[MY_SANDBOX]/_slds/fonts/v2.3.0/SalesforceSans-Regular.woff'
>   from origin '[MY_STATIC_SITE]' has been blocked by
>   CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin '[MY_STATIC_SITE]' is
>   therefore not allowed access.
>
> aura_proddebug.js:2411 GET
>   https://[MY_STATIC_SITE]/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=8.2.0
>   net::ERR_ABORTED

However, I have listed the static site in the sandbox's CORS and remote site settings.  I have also made sure CORS is enabled on the S3 bucket.

S3 CORS settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Static Site Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="[MY_SANDBOX]/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.7.0/jsforce.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
    <script>
        jsforce.browser.init({
            loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com',
            clientId: '[    MY_CLIENT_ID    ]',
            redirectUri: '[ MY_REDIRECT ]'
        });
        function login(){
            jsforce.browser.login();
        }
        jsforce.browser.on('connect', function(conn) {
            if(conn.accessToken && jsforce.browser.isLoggedIn()){
                $Lightning.use("c:DEPENDENCY_APP", function() {
                    $Lightning.createComponent("c:CONTAINER_COMPONENT",
                    {},
                    "lightningout",
                    function(cmp) {
                        //nothing yet
                    });
                },
                'https://[MY_URL].lightning.force.com', 
                conn.accessToken 
                );
            }
        });
    </script>
        <div id="lightningout">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The lightning out app looks like this:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:MY_COMPONENT" type="COMPONENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

The lightning component looks like this:

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="My_Ctrl">
    <div aura:id="flowContainer">
        <lightning:flow aura:id="newFlow" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

I was under the impression the SLDS styles come over with `ltng:outApp` apps. The only SLDS styles applied are the button colors, but not the shape/font/size of them.  The fonts, grid system, and everything else is missing.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't come out of the box with lightning. Either you need to extend force:slds in your lightning app or use `<apex:lightning/>` in your Vf page but as you are not using vf page you can't use `<apex:lightning/>`

As you are already extending ltng:outapp you can't extends force:slds at same time so as a solution upload slds css in your s3 bucket and add that in your static html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css file path from s3 bucket">
```

You can download this from https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads

Comment: As I mentioned before, its an external site hosting a lightning out app. No visualforce. so `<apex:lightning/>` wouldnt do much.  And I think you're right. I think I misread the documentation around `ltng:outapp`. I'm pretty sure styling comes through in a VF environment, but not an external environment.  I will probably end up hosting the CSS myself, unfortunately.

Comment: i agree we do have `lightningStylesheets` tag but that doesn't work in salesforce classic (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm). so at the end in your case you need to host css

Comment: So I tried that and it had no effect.  I was initially confused because the "app" starts out with a flow, and then displays some information in a lightning component.  The lightning component stuff renders fine, even without the `link` reference to the SLDS stylesheet, but everything inside the flow renders incorrectly.

Comment: You parent div id should be lightning in static html body

Comment: the id is `lightningout` because that's what i specified in the `CreateComponent` parameter.  should `lightning` be added to the div id to enable styling? do you have any documentation around that?

Comment: i will correct myself, it is class. it should be <div class="slds-scope"> (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-lightning-design-system-visualforce/steps/slds-vf-02-create-page) read #2 before step 3.

Comment: I tried adding "slds-scope" to the parent div to no avail.  I have double and tripple checked the SDLS stylesheet is being loaded in the static site.  Here's a screen cap showing the div, and the unstyled flow: https://gyazo.com/6c5dea15a1217380069c997b7d21a691

Comment: can you share your public website link, i can take a look

Comment: Unfortunately, you will need to authenticate (oauth) into the sandbox to see the flow.