# SLDS not applied to flow when used in Lightning Out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, lightning-out

I have a `Lightning Out` app, hosted in a S3 bucket, that launches a flow.  Everything works and is styled as it should be until the flow is launched. The input styles revert back to "normal", the date pickers are broken, and the buttons are ugly. I tried including the SDLS stylesheet in the static site but it had no affect.

Here's what its supposed to look like:

[image]
.

Here's what it comes out as

[image]

As I previously mentioned, all tables, grids, and other buttons in the lightning components work and are styled correctly, but everything inside the flow is broken.  Here's the markup for the flow in the lightning component:

```
<div aura:id="newBidContainer" class="slds">
    <lightning:flow aura:id="newBidFlow" onstatuschange="{!c.handleNewBidStatusChange}" class="slds-scope" />
</div>
```

I have tried adding `class="slds"` and `class="slds-scope"` but there was no change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the context markup?

Comment: Sure, check out https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207487/lightning-out-slds-weirdness . It was my original question when I thought it might be a CORS issue rejecting the CSS assets, but it turns out that everything after the flow works fine... its just the flow that's broken.

Comment: What scoping class did you use? Pretty sure you need to apply that to a container element wrapped around your flow.

Comment: I didnt generate a scoped version of SDLS if that's what you're asking. I just downloaded the package from https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/ and included the asset folder in my static site.  That's why I tried `class="slds"` and `class="slds-scope"` as a last-ditch effort to see if that had any effect... which sadly did not.

Comment: Have you tried to upload slds css downloaded from https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads into your s3 bucket and add that in your static html code
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css file path from s3 bucket"> ?

Comment: yes, and I have confirmed it is being loaded correctly.

Comment: Bumping this question.  Has this been resolved by anyone?

Comment: @Jake as of the last release it had not been resolved.  I have not checked in winter '19 though.